# How do I get licensing information of confluence via rest API?

Tags: jira, licensing, confluence, jira-rest-api, atlassian-fisheye

I was trying to automate the notification on Atlassian tools license expiry. I have been looking at JIRA and found below REST API URL which gives license details.

`https://jira.company.com/rest/plugins/applications/1.0/installed/jira-software/license`

But, I dint get any clue on how to fetch licensing details for Confluence and Fiisheye.

I could see below REST API url. But it doesnt provide enough information.

`https://confluence.company.com/rest/plugins/1.0/com.atlassian.confluence-key/license`

JSON:

```
{
"links": {
"self": "/rest/plugins/1.0/com.atlassian.confluence-key/license",
"alternate": "/rest/plugins/1.0/available/com.atlassian.confluence-key",
"license": "/rest/plugins/1.0/com.atlassian.confluence-key/license",
"update-license": "/rest/plugins/1.0/com.atlassian.confluence-key/license",
"license-callback": "https://confluence.company.com/plugins/servlet/upm/license/com.atlassian.confluence",
"try": "https://my.atlassian.com/addon/try/com.atlassian.confluence",
"new": "https://my.atlassian.com/addon/new/com.atlassian.confluence"
},
"pluginKey": "com.atlassian.confluence",
"valid": false,
"active": false
}
```

Please share your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confluence doesn't provide extensive information on license details via API. We've raised a feature request for this, which you can find below.

https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONFSERVER-56110?_ga=2.51685408.866579204.1549874240-1463697888.1544017536

Answer (score 1):

The above issue has been solved an since Confluence 7.1. You have some extension points for confluence available:

```
/rest/license/1.0/license/details <-- expiryDate available

/rest/license/1.0/license/maxUsers

/rest/license/1.0/license/userCount

/rest/license/1.0/license/remainingSeats
```